# How to bind contact name, phone and contact photo in SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, contacts, adapter

I'm able to retrieve contact name and phone, but how to retrieve contact photo in one query?

```
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { Contacts.People._ID, Contacts.PeopleColumns.NAME, Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };
    Cursor c = a.managedQuery(Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, Contacts.People.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    return (new SimpleCursorAdapter(a, 
            R.layout.list_row, 
            c, 
            new String[] { Contacts.PeopleColumns.NAME, Contacts.Phones.NUMBER  }, 
            new int[] { R.id.toptext, R.id.bottomtext }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the same boat (and for android-3 through android-5 to boot)!

I don't see a column for a photo in either 1.x or 2.x, so I'm just about resigned to using a **CursorAdapter** with a makeshift View Holder (private class, assigned to the anon view tag) for good measure, then using **loadContactPhoto** in **bindView** as needed.

The trick there would appear to be avoiding undue/excess scaling (e.g., cache the results of **Bitmap.createScaledBitmap** for each photo, at the very least?), lest the view slows down again and you lose the benefits of having a cursor-driven list in the first place.

I know, getting messy. I'm sure *there's got to be a better way*! Well, I'm hopeful there is. :)